# Trying to load JSON results into an array

Tags: ios, arrays, afnetworking

I am getting JSON results with the following code but get the error: `-[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.`  I need to take the JSON that is in string format and get it into an array so that I can use it.

my refreshStream2 method is as follows

```
-(void)refreshStream2 
    {

 [[API sharedInstance] commandWithParams:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                             @"stream2",@"command",
                                             nil]
                               onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *json) {
                                   //got stream

  NSArray* list = [json objectForKey:@"result"];
                                NSLog(@"%@", list);
                                NSDictionary* photo = [list objectAtIndex:0];
                                NSLog(@"%@", photo);
                               [self showStream2:[photo objectForKey:@"Address"]];
     }];

}
```

I then call the showStream2 method

```
-(void)showStream2:(NSArray*)stream {
     [_tableView reloadData];
     self.myList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
         NSDictionary* myTitle  = [stream objectAtIndex:i];   // I GET ERROR HERE!!
         [self.myList addObject: myTitle];
     }
 }
```

*JSON Output******

2013-05-29 13:06:05.581 app[16335:907] 
    (
        {
        Address = test2;
        BarName = test1;
    },
        {
        Address = test2;
        BarName = test;
    },
        {
        Address = test2;
        BarName = test;
    },
        {
        Address = test2;
        BarName = test;
    },
        {
        Address = test2;
        BarName = test;
    },
        {
        Address = test2;
        BarName = test;
    },
        {
        Address = test2;
        BarName = test;
    },
        {
        Address = test2;
        BarName = test;
    },
        {
        Address = test2;
        BarName = test;
    },
        {
        Address = test2;
        BarName = test;
    }
    )

Comment: It seems that your `list` object is a string and not an NSArry as you might think. That's why the crash. You should also post the JSON structure.

Comment: I suspect that you have a JSON string (the thing you're calling "json") that needs to be parsed into the appropriate data structure before you can use it.

Comment: Can you NSLog the json object and put the output here ?

Comment: This is nearly identical to your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815872/iphone-unrecognized-selector-error-when-streaming-to-nsdictionary

Comment: Added JSON.  Apologies for similar question but I am trying to figure out the correct syntax for getting my JSON into an array structure.

Comment: list already is an array of dictionaries. Is that not what you want? If not, then you need to say what you do want.

Comment: What I am ultimately trying to do is get the JSON results into the rows of my UITable.  For that I need those results as an array (as I understand it). So I need the results to go into "myList" array by adding the myTitle in the for loop. [self.myList addObject: myTitle];

Comment: What you posted is not a JOSN format. It's a simple string. You should validate your JSON format before you use it ;)

Comment: As I said before list is already an array, you can just use self.myList = list; No need to do any loops. photo gives you the first dictionary in list and [photo objectForKey:@"Address"] gives you a string, so you don't want to be passing that to showStream2:(there's no need for the showStream2: method at all).